# C++ Variables - declare and define. Inheritance

Tags: c++, variables, scope, declare

Let's have a C++ object A. There are two variables (VAR1 and VAR2) in A accessible to its children.
Object B extends A and has one private variable VAR3 it can also access VAR1 and VAR2. Each instance of A/B has its own variables.

Would this be the right way of declaring and defining the variables?

**A.h**

```
class A {
protected:
    static std::string const VAR1;
    static std::string VAR2;
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
using namespace std;
string const A::VAR1 = "blah";
string A::VAR2;
```

**B.h**

```
#include "A.h"
class B : public A {
private:
    static std::string VAR3;

public:
    B(std::string const v1, std::string const v2);
    void m() const;
};
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"
using namespace std;

string B::VAR3;

B::B(string const v1, string const v2) {
    VAR2 = v1;
    VAR3 = v2;
}

void B::m() const {
    // Print VAR1, VAR2 and VAR3.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Each instance of A/B has its own variables.
>
> Would this be the right way of declaring and defining the variables?

No.  You've declared `A`'s members as `static` which means they are class-variables, not instance-variables.  Each instance doesn't get it's own copy.  Instead, they all share the same instance.

Make then non-`static`:

```
class A {
protected:
    std::string const VAR1;
    std::string VAR2;
};
```

... and then, of course, you don't need the global initializer so get rid of this:

```
string const A::VAR1 = "blah";
string A::VAR2;
```

...and if you want `VAR1` to have a default value every time `A` is instantiated, then you can do that in the class' initializer list (or in the ctor body, if you're a punk :) ):

```
A::A() : VAR1("blah") {};
```

Comment: @downvoter:  please explain so that this post may be improved

Comment: @downvoter:  if you didn't like being called a punk, I was just being facetious :)

Comment: Hi and thanks. I just got a little bit confused after reading about extern vs static variables... So, to sum up. I make all declarations non-static, remove all definitions and assign values in the constructors. Right?

Comment: extern and static both have so many overloaded meanings its quite easy to get confused. Most of the time the best approach is to leave the qualifiers off unless you know you need them and why.

Answer (score 1):

*Each instance of A/B has its own variables.*

Not so.  You've declared them `static`.  Stop doing that and you might get closer to your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

No, you got it wrong.

- The problem requires each instance to have its own set of variables, so why are you declaring `A` and `B`'s data as `static`?
- You don't need to implement anything. The problem just asks you to declare the types and their member data.
- The constructor isn't necessary either as far as what the requirements ask you to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
protected:
    char var1,var2;
};

class B: public A {
private:
    char var3;
};

void main()
{
    B b1;
    b1.var3='a';
}
```